# In Grafana, how do I display a table of system status using a normal DB table AND highlight based on text value?

Tags: plugins, datatable, grafana

I will start of by saying that I'm new to Grafana.
I have a database table that is being updated externally that has say 15 columns of information on a given set of servers. I'm just trying to display the server name and current status and change the color of the row based on that status (Norm, Alert, Down) ... ideally those would be links to a detail page.

I tried the included table display which looks like it should handle it ***but the coloring options don't seem to work based on plain dumb text*** in a column or it would be perfect because it says it will color by row and includes the ability to make each row a link essentially.

[grafana screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wG6lC.png)

I have tried with and without quotes in the Threshold values. It says in the hover help you can use comma separated values but does not seem to work for me. (I am thinking it's my config or usage btw)

Every other plugin I can find that says it wants to do this errors out when I tell it I have a table of data and not some live feed.